# How to create a MELA.ILogger from a Serilog.ILogger for use in a .NET Standard library

Tags: c#, serilog

I am converting a .NET Standard utility library from console logging to `ILogger` logging.

The library consists static utility classes, and I am exposing a static `ILogger` property to be set by users, to point to whatever logging system they want to use.

I want my .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5 console apps to use Serilog for logging, and assign the library `ILogger` to Serilog, with all the goodness that comes with Serilog.
I am not using DI in the utility library, as it is static methods, not "service" classes.

How do I manually (not using DI) create a `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger` from a `Serilog.ILogger` or a `Serilog.Extensions.Logging.SerilogLoggerFactory`.

Any suggestions on an easier way vs. the example code?

```
// How to create a "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger" from a "Serilog.ILogger"?
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger = Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.NullLogger.Instance;

// https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/blob/dev/samples/Sample/Program.cs
LoggerProviderCollection providerCollection = new LoggerProviderCollection();

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.Providers(providerCollection)
    .CreateLogger();

ServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton(providerCollection);
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory>(sc =>
{
    LoggerProviderCollection loggerProviderCollection = sc.GetService<LoggerProviderCollection>();
    SerilogLoggerFactory serilogLoggerFactory = new SerilogLoggerFactory(null, true, loggerProviderCollection);

    foreach (ILoggerProvider loggerProvider in sc.GetServices<ILoggerProvider>())
        serilogLoggerFactory.AddProvider(loggerProvider);

    return serilogLoggerFactory;
});

serviceCollection.AddLogging(logging => logging.AddConsole());

ServiceProvider serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
ILogger<Program> programLogger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

logger = programLogger;
logger.LogInformation("Testing testing");
```

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution with simpler code:

```
// https://www.nexmo.com/legacy-blog/2020/02/10/adaptive-library-logging-with-microsoft-extensions-logging-dr

// Default : "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"

// Serilog logger
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} {Level} {SourceContext} | {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}", 
                        theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Code)
    .CreateLogger();

// MEL logger factory
LoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
loggerFactory.AddSerilog(Log.Logger);

// MEL logger
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Foo");
logger.LogInformation("Testing testing");
```

Comment: This helped me. I don't know how to get this to resolve in a controller yet, but I'm a lot closer now.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me.

```
// existing serilog logger
Serilog.ILogger logger = Log.ForContext<MyType>();

// create MEL logger from serilog logger
var loggerFactory = new Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory();
loggerFactory.AddSerilog(logger);
var melLogger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyType>();

// sample log message
melLogger.LogInformation("Sample log message");
```

Related NuGet packages:

- Serilog - for serilog
- Serilog.Extensions.Logging - for AddSerilog method
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging - for LogInformation method
- Microsoft.Extensions.LoggingAbstractions - for logging factory

Serilog was configured in a separate project, that project included the Serilog.AspNetCore NuGet package only.

The reason why I needed to make a MEL logger was due to a 3rd party library.  That library only accepted an MEL logger provider.  This solution did not use dependency injection for the ILogger, so I had to do the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest way I could find:

```
Using Serilog;
```

Then in your method.  Note:  The melLogger in the snippet below is a new instance of the logger

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Debug(restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Verbose)
    .CreateLogger();

Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger melLogger= new SerilogLoggerProvider(Log.Logger)
                                               .CreateLogger("WHATVER_YOU_WANT");
```

Then to use this system wide via dependency injection, the secret sauce being .UseSeriLog():

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .UseSerilog()                
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup(typeof(StartUp));
    });
```